# Cramers v when r = 1 and k = 2

Tags: chi-squared-test, cramers-v

I have just read that 'Cramér's V may also be applied to goodness of fit chi-squared models when there is a 1×k table (e.g.: r=1)'. It then goes on to say 'In this case k is taken as the number of optional outcomes and it functions as a measure of tendency towards a single outcome.'  The source  is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_V
So if Cramer’s v = sqrt (x2/n * min k – 1, r – 1) what would I multiply by in my case where k = 2 and r = 1?

Comment: Can you please give the source for this?

Comment: I don't really understand what the sentence `In this case k is taken as the number of optional outcomes and it functions as a measure of tendency towards a single outcome.`, even given my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you divide the chi-square value by N and (k - 1), you will get a statistic [that ranges from 0 to 1 when conducting a chi-square goodness of fit test with equally distributed theoretical probabilities (e.g. 0.50 and 0.50 in your case). [See this source](http://rcompanion.org/handbook/H_03.html).  See also [the examples and documentation for this function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rcompanion/versions/1.13.2/topics/cramerVFit).

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure either because in my case k = 2, so therefore 2 - 1 = 1. Would I then multiply by 1 e.g. sqrt (X2/n * 1) ? This would give me the same effect size as if calculating the effect size using Phi. If I was using the method that you describe above, how do I report that as an effect size?

Comment: To report it, you would have to explain how you calculated it; it's not a standard statistic.  I would recommend also reporting something more common like the odds ratio or the simple proportions.

Comment: Thank you. Would it also be an option to calculate the effect size as above e.g. sqrt (x2/n*1) and then report this as Cramer's V?

Comment: Yes, I would call that a"variant of Cramer's V" and explain how it's calculated, because it's not typical to calculate Cramer's V for 1 x tables.

Answer (score 0):

While Mangiafico's response more than answers the question, I wish to add a bit of clarification which I have found personally useful.  (And my hope is to record in one place some of the information I have located on this topic.)

In brief, I was recently teaching a mathematical statistics course, and on the online homework system I use, I added a question to an assignment on multinomial distributions and goodness-of-fit tests.  Curiously, it was a question I had written some time ago.  When students started complaining that the question wasn't grading correctly, I did some investigating.  And this is how I located this thread.

First, the statistic being referred to in this thread does not quite appear to me to be the Cramér's $V$.  And, it took some time to locate a relatively easily accessible reference, but I did locate one.

Lomax & Hahs-Vaughn (2012) introduce an effect size (not labelled $V$ or such) for a multinomial goodness-of-fit (GoF) test (p.220)
$$\text{effect size} = \frac{\chi^2}{N(J-1)}$$
where $\chi^2$ is the test statistic for the GoF test, $N$ is the total sample size, and $J$ is the number of distinct categories.  The reason I'm reluctant to label this as a version of Cramér's V is because it does not include the square-root, and this is not an association problem.  (For reference, Cramér's $V$ is a measure of association—not fit—and is given by
$$V=\sqrt{\frac{\chi^2}{N \cdot \min(r-1,c-1)}}$$
as indicated here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Other_metrics.)

The other common effect size that is reported for general chi-square tests is Cohen's W ([https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen's_w](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Cohen%27s_w)), which can be expressed as
$$W = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^J \frac{(p_j-\pi_j)^2}{\pi_j}}$$
or equivlalently
$$W = \sqrt{\frac{\chi^2}{N}}.$$
While this value can range from 0 to values larger than 1, the effect size proposed here does indeed range from 0 to 1, if the assumption is for an equiprobably distribution among the $J$ categories.

So, in summary, there appear to be three effect sizes that are related to each other in some fashion.  The first two are for fit to a multinomial distributions, and the last is for an association.  Summarized here, they are

- for a $1\times J$ table: Cohen's $W = \sqrt{\frac{\chi^2}{N}}$
- for a $1\times J$ table: quasi-$V = \frac{\chi^2}{N\cdot(J-1)}$
- for a $r\times c$ table: Cramér's $V = \sqrt{\frac{\chi^2}{N \cdot \min(r-1,c-1)}}$

---

As a brief addendum, I include here the proof that this quasi-$V$ obtains the (maximal) value of 1 if the expected frequencies are based on $J$ equiprobable categories and all of the frequency appears in only one of the $J$ categories.
$$\begin{align}V &= \frac{\chi^2}{N\cdot(J-1)} \\
&= \frac{1}{N\cdot(J-1)} \left(\frac{(N-\frac{N}{J})^2}{\frac{N}{J}} + (J-1)\frac{(0-\frac{N}{J})^2}{\frac{N}{J}}\right) \\
&= \frac{J}{J-1} \left((1-\frac{1}{J})^2 + (J-1)(\frac{1}{J})^2\right)\\
&= \frac{J}{J-1} \left(\left(\frac{J-1}{J}\right)^2 + \frac{J-1}{J^2}\right)\\
&= \frac{J-1}{J} + \frac{1}{J} \\
&= 1\end{align}$$